# Any suggestion to this crypto puzzle?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I am strugling for several days to solve this crypto problem on a website. Really appreciate if you can direct me for a solution. Xored everything with numbers sequences without luck. Is there some kind of frequency analiz or tool to help? What should be the method to seek?

THE WORLD IS YOURS IF 
LPM ANEOOIHL JGU BP4EJB5LJ PK 0JE OFFL3PSKPW BRT1H FZ N EK14UP T2C MAYA MXWH 30KI04 ZHN GD0 QNSOM

Website says "There is no secret key. Encryption is algorithmic and based on XORing."

Answer (score 1):

The cyphertext includes digits and spaces.  I would start by looking at a monoalphabetic substitution with an alphabet of 36 characters: a ... z0 ...9.  To start with "LPM" might map to "the" in the plaintext as a common three letter word that often starts a piece of text.

Failing that, then try a 36 character Vigenère.

You can probably assume that the spaces are correct.  If not, then try a 37 character alphabet with space added as a character.

Comment: There is also "N" (BRT1H FZ N) which is probably "A". Vigenere says needs key. this doesnt need key.  There are 8 different 3 letter-words.